# eclipse shortcut xml for jdeveloper

Tags: eclipse, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, jdeveloper

Can someone please provide the eclipse shortcut xml to load it in jdeveloper? 
thanks in advance.

I have tried to load keyboard schemes from eclipse in jdeveloper. But it is not helping. In order to import the shortcuts by the import option, I need the shortcut xml.

Answer (score 1):

There is already Eclipse key mapping in JDeveloper - no need to import. Do this:
Preferences->Shortcut Keys->More Actions->Load Keyboard Schema
Eclipse is one of the options there.

Comment: Thanks Shay. I tried that option but I don't see any changes in the shortcut keys. Still I can see the default shortcut keys of jdeveloper. Is there any xml for the eclipse shortcuts which can be loaded into jdeveloper ?